# How do I sort column A based on column B in a pivot table using pywin32?

Tags: python, excel, sorting, pywin32, win32com

So I'm currently using the pywin32com library to create a pivot table just like excel would (has to be this way). Everything is working thus far, but I can't sort. I'm constantly given the error as follows:

"pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "We can't make this change for the selected cells because it will affect a PivotTable. Use the field list to change the report. If you are trying to insert or delete cells, move the PivotTable and try again.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

This is my code:

```
def addPivotTable(fileName):

    cwd = os.getcwd()

    print("cwd from addpivot table - ", cwd)
    XLFile = os.path.join(cwd, fileName)

    #launch excel application
    xlApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False

    #create workbook : wb and ws
    #reference workbooks
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(XLFile)

    #reference worksheets
    ws_Original = wb.Worksheets("Original")
    ws_Pivot = wb.Worksheets("Pivot") 

    #create pivot table cache connection 
    pt_cache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(1,ws_Original.Range("E:E").CurrentRegion)

    #create pivot table designer/editor
    pt = pt_cache.CreatePivotTable(ws_Pivot.Range("A3"), "myreport_summary")

    #row and column grandtotals
    pt.ColumnGrand = True
    pt.RowGrand = True

    #change report layout
    pt.RowAxisLayout(1)   #RowAxisLayout(1) for tabular form

    #change pivot table style
    #Select from Design tab, try out Medium9 or Medium3
    pt.TableStyle2 = "pivotStyleMedium9"   

    #add cols
    field_cols = {} 
    field_cols["Claim Number"] = pt.PivotFields("Claim Number")

    #insert col field to pivot table design
    field_cols["Claim Number"].Orientation = 1   # 2 for col orientation


    #add value
    field_values = {} 
    field_values["Claim Number"] = pt.PivotFields("Claim Number")

    #insert data/value to pivot table design
    field_values["Claim Number"].Orientation = 4   # 4 for data/value
    field_values["Claim Number"].Function = -4112  # -4112 for xlCount
    field_values["Claim Number"].NumberFormat = "#,##0"


    # Get reference to column to sort by
    column_to_sort_by = ws_Pivot.PivotFields('Count of Claim Number')

    # Get reference to first PivotItem in column
    first_pivot_item = column_to_sort_by.PivotItems(1)

    pt.PivotCache().Refresh()

    # Sort the first column based on the second column in ascending order.
    ws_Pivot.Range("A:A").Sort(Key1= ws_Pivot.Range("A:A"), Key2=ws_Pivot.Range("B:B"), 
    Order1= 1, Header=1) # <--- Where I'm sorting

    wb.Save()
    wb.Close(True)
```

This is the line of code I'm trying to use to sort:

```
 ws_Pivot.Range("A:A").Sort(Key1= ws_Pivot.Range("A:A"), Key2=ws_Pivot.Range("B:B"), 
 Order1= 1, Header=1)
```

Any help is much much appreciated (as it seems impossible to find any proper documentation for this library). Thanks in advance!